# Match Float with actual type `p0 -> a0'

Tags: haskell

I had this working when all the types were doubles however i need them to be in this format, any idea how I can solve my error?

```
areaCalcuator:: Int -> Float
priceCalcuator :: Int -> Int -> Float
--isMoreExpensive :: Bool

areaCalcuator x = ((fromIntegral x / 2) ^2)* pi

priceCalcuator x y = let area = (\z -> (((fromIntegral x / 2) ^2)* pi))
                     in (0.001 * area) + ((fromIntegral y)*0.002 * area) * 1.5
```

The new error I got was

```
 * Couldn't match expected type `Float' with actual type `p0 -> a0'
    * Probable cause: `(+)' is applied to too few arguments
      In the expression:
        (0.001 * area) + ((fromIntegral y) * 0.002 * area) * 1.5
      In the expression:
        let area = (\ z -> (((fromIntegral x / 2) ^ 2) * pi))
        in (0.001 * area) + ((fromIntegral y) * 0.002 * area) * 1.5
      In an equation for `priceCalcuator':
          priceCalcuator x y
            = let area = (\ z -> ...)
              in (0.001 * area) + ((fromIntegral y) * 0.002 * area) * 1.5
    * Relevant bindings include
        area :: forall p. p -> a0
          (bound at C:\\Users\Ellis\OneDrive\Year 2\CS-205 Declarative Programming\CW1\Haskell-Cw1\Coursework1.hs:13:26)
   |
14 |                      in (0.001 * area) + ((fromIntegral y)*0.002 * area) * 1.5
   |
```

I believe my lack of understanding with haskell is what caused this issue

Comment: You want to look at `fromIntegral`.

Comment: Ivetried the fomIntegral but im getting a new error : areaCalcuator:: Int -> Float
priceCalcuator :: Int -> Int -> Float
--isMoreExpensive :: Bool

areaCalcuator x = ((fromIntegral x / 2) ^2)* pi

priceCalcuator x y = let area = (\z -> (((fromIntegral x / 2) ^2)* pi))
                     in (0.001 * area) + ((fromIntegral y)*0.002 * area) * 1.5

 * Couldn't match expected type `Float' with actual type `p0 -> a0'

Comment: Why restrict the types so much? For example, the inferred type for `areaCalculator = ((x/2) ^ 2) * pi` is `Floating a => a -> a`. The inferred type for your updated definition is `(Integral a2, Floating a1) => a2 -> a1`.

Comment: Please [edit] the question with relevant updates, comments don't work well for this. Also please format the compiler messages as code.

Comment: Now the question doesn't match the title though.

Comment: I've managed to solve the errors thanks to @n.m. and chepner I've also reformatted the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to n.m for the fromIntegral I managed to rewrite the code so it works which also fixed my second error.

```
priceCalcuator :: Int -> Int -> Float
isMoreExpensive :: Bool
priceCalcuator x y = let area = (((fromIntegral x / 2) ^2)* pi)
                     in  ((0.001 * area) + ((fromIntegral y * area)*0.002))*1.5
```

Apologies to the poor formatting
If anyone can explain this then please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Alternately you could also do it this way:

```
areaCalculator :: Floating a => a -> a
areaCalculator x = ((x / 2) ^2) * pi

priceCalculator :: Double -> Double -> Double
priceCalculator x y = 
 (  (areaCalculator x * 0.001) 
  + (areaCalculator x * 0.002 * y)) * 1.5
```

Comment: I had something similar to that to start with, however a requirement was that for the "priceClacuator" it had to be > priceCalculator :: Integer -> Integer -> Float
As to satisfy an automatic test

Comment: ah cool, wasn't too sure from original question but see you've edited it now :)